# Unable to load entire page using Selenium PhantomJs driver

Tags: java, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, phantomjs

I am using Selenium library in Java to scrap a site.I am using PhantomJsDriver as webdriver.This site has some urls present in list(li) tags which I am interested in.The problem is that the site has 64 (li) elements but I am receiving only 16 (li) elements.Here is my code:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps=new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE_PATH_PROPERTY    , "Path");
WebDriver driver=new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.get("Some Website");

WebDriverWait wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 600);

wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
    boolean resetCount=true;
    int counter=5;
    @Override
    public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
        if(resetCount){
            ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript(
                    "   window.mssCount="+counter+";\r\n" + 
                    "   window.mssJSDelay=function mssJSDelay(){\r\n" + 
                    "       if((typeof jQuery != 'undefined') && (jQuery.active !== 0 || $(\":animated\").length !== 0))\r\n" + 
                    "           window.mssCount="+counter+";\r\n" + 
                    "       window.mssCount-->0 &&\r\n" + 
                    "       setTimeout(window.mssJSDelay,window.mssCount+1);\r\n" + 
                    "   }\r\n" + 
                    "   window.mssJSDelay();");
            resetCount=false;
        }
        boolean ready=false;
        try{
            ready=-1==((Long) ((JavascriptExecutor) d).executeScript(
                    "if(typeof window.mssJSDelay!=\"function\"){\r\n" + 
                    "   window.mssCount="+counter+";\r\n" + 
                    "   window.mssJSDelay=function mssJSDelay(){\r\n" + 
                    "       if((typeof jQuery != 'undefined') && (jQuery.active !== 0 || $(\":animated\").length !== 0))\r\n" + 
                    "           window.mssCount="+counter+";\r\n" + 
                    "       window.mssCount-->0 &&\r\n" + 
                    "       setTimeout(window.mssJSDelay,window.mssCount+1);\r\n" + 
                    "   }\r\n" + 
                    "   window.mssJSDelay();\r\n" + 
                    "}\r\n" + 
                    "return window.mssCount;"));
        }
        catch (NoSuchWindowException a){
            a.printStackTrace();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return ready;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Timeout waiting for documentNotActive script");
    }
});


BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:\\abc.txt")));
bw.write(driver.getPageSource());
bw.close();
driver.quit();
```

I have reused the code in wait.until() from an answer.My question is that why is it returning only 16 elements? I assume that it should return none or all elements.Is there any limit on number of tags or document size?.What is the solution here?

Answer (score 0):

try to add

> An implicit wait is to tell WebDriver to poll the DOM for a certain
>   amount of time when trying to find an element or elements if they are
>   not immediately available. The default setting is 0. Once set, the
>   implicit wait is set for the life of the WebDriver object instance.

```
WebDriver driver=new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: You should probably elaborate some more on why that would help

Comment: it suppose to wait a little longer for the elements to complete, try it.

Comment: Thank you for your help but it didn't work.What I didn't notice was that the site was appending the DOM on scrolling.So now I am able to fetch all the elements.